# Reload Ajax Datatable with paramater POST when clieked

Tags: ajax, datatable

I have databaled like these.

```
var table = $('#rep-ship-plan');
    var target = table.attr('data-table');
    var fDate = $("#fRange").val();
    var tDate = $("#sRange").val();
    var BuyerCode = $("#Buyer").val();
    var oTable = table.on( 'processing.dt', function ( e, settings, processing ) {
            if (processing) {
                $(this).find('tbody').addClass('load1 csspinner');
            } else{
                $(this).find('tbody').removeClass('load1 csspinner');
            };
        } ).DataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "scrollY": "200px",
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "paging": false,
            "ajax": {
                "url" : host+"datatables",
                "type": "POST",
                "data" :{
                           target: target
                        }
            },
            "columnDefs": [{
                "targets": [ 0 ],
                "className": "details-control",
            }],
            "fnDrawCallback": function(oSetting) {
              $('.currency').formatCurrency({symbol: ''});
            }
        });
```

But my problem is i wanna reload my table with data POST when i click button search. How to sent post to ajax or how to reload my ajax with my new `POST` data (input)??

NOTE : I'm using POST cause if i'm using GET it to make long URL, and my server cant hold it (I have 42 Columns on Datatables)

Answer (score 0):

Attach event listener to your search button

```
$('#searchButtonId').on('click', function(){});
```

And place into your click callback function DataTable reload method as your data gets posted

```
datatable.ajax.reload();
```

Something like that

```
$('#searchButtonId').on('click', function () {
        //Grab necessary data and put it into variable 'data'
        $.post('/url/to/script/updating/DataTable/source', {
            data: //your data here
        }, function () {
            //Do your stuff on successfully POSTed data
            //Refresh your DataTable
            datatable.ajax.reload();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Well it working if reloaded, but how do i send my data parameter to ajax with `POST` Data??

Comment: As you click your 'search' button, callback function is supposed to POST necessary data, which you process at server end to update DataTable source. Upon successfully executed POST-request, you simply reload DataTable feeding it with up to date data.

Comment: No still not working, and why i need update, i just need `FILTER` not `UPDATE` data